# How do I update another table from insert script of some table on microsoft azure server?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

```
function insert(item, user, request) {
      intoo(); 
      item.mid=idd;
      request.execute({success:updateGroup}); 

      function updateGroup(results){
          var group_gid;    
          var groups=tables.getTable('groups');
          groups
          .where(({ gid : item.gid}))
          .read();
          group_gid=getItem(results);
          group_gid.appended_mid=group_gid.appended_mid+" "+item.mid; 
          groups.update(group_gid);       
     }


     function getItem(results){
          for (var item in results) {
              return item; 
          }
     }
```

}

The item is inserted in this table(of whose this insert script is) bur the groups table is not being updated.
NOTE:The tables are not in SQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should work

```
var groups=tables.getTable('groups');
groups
.where(({ gid : item.gid}))
.read({success:updateGroup});
function updateGroup(results){
    var group_gid;        
    group_gid=results[0];
    group_gid.appended_mid=group_gid.appended_mid+" "+item.mid; 
    groups.update(group_gid);
    request.execute();       
}
```